# Accessing a private member without getter function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sum

I'm preparing for an exam, and I'm trying to solve a question I suspect might be unsolvable.

In the supermarket, every item you buy has a name, cost, and quantity.

So the teacher defined this class:

```
class items {
public:
    items(string, double, int);
    void InputItems ();  
    void SetCount (int const);
    string GetName () const;
    string toString () const;

private:
    string name;
    double cost;
    int count;
}
```

But when you go to the supermarket, you don't always buy several copies of just one item. You can buy several items. So our question was to define a class `Purchase` that handles an array of type `items`.

I defined it like this:

```
class Purchase
{
    private:
        items *arr;
        int max_items,current_items;
    public:
        Purchase(int New_max_items){
            max_items=New_max_items;
            current_items=0;
            arr= new items("",0,0)[max_items];
        }
        void AddItem(items const newitems);
        items RemoveItem(string const name);
        int Find(string const name);
        int const sum();
        int get_now();
        items &operator[](int) const;
}
```

The exercise asked that I implement `items &operator[](int) const;` and `int const sum();`. And I managed to implement the operator:

```
goods & Purchase::operator[](int i) const
{
    if ((i>=0)&&(i<current_items))
        return arr[i];
}
```

No problem there.

**The problem is with the function to sum the entire cost of the purchase.**

I can't access `arr[i].cost` and `arr[i].count` directly, since they are private members of the class `Items`, and I can't get them indirectly since the teacher did not include getter functions for those class members in his class `Items`.

Is it possible to write a program that returns the sum of the entire purchase without changing the class `Items`?

Comment: Although this is bad practice and defeats the purpose of access specifiers, you can access private members by dereferencing `arr[i]` and using pointer arithmetic to get to the member you're trying to access.

Comment: @BaherRamzy - actually that's undefined behaviour, there can be an arbitrary amount of padding, except before the first member.

Comment: Will "friend" work for you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class

Comment: Is there a requirement *not* to modify the `items` class? Otherwise just add the functions needed, or make `Purchase` a `friend`. If you're not allowed to modify `items` then the teacher screwed up (or screwing you up).

Comment: The is not a good way without changing `items`

Comment: There is a requirement not to touch Items. That is a closed black box for us. We can't touch it. How will friend help in this situation? It is possible the teacher made a mistake, but I'm not experienced enough to make that call.

Comment: The only way I can see to get the cost of the item without dirty tricks is if the `toString()` function returns a string with the cost in it you can parse the string and get the cost of the item.

Comment: Teachers are humans just like anybody else, and just like any other human they make mistakes. Talk to the teacher, ask him or her about it. Maybe the test is about you daring to question the teacher? :)

Comment: I guess the teacher made a mistake there. We don't know how toString was implemented so we don't know where in the string will be the cost / count. Was my constructor for purchase ok though? Will it really be an array of initialized Items?

Comment: Your teacher's design is a bit awkward – I wouldn't consider the items themselves to have a quantity, but that you purchase a certain quantity of items. And it's very odd to only be able to purchase items in predetermined quantities.

Comment: Is "change school" an acceptable answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the purpose is to have a table outside the classes on item names and cost.
So you can call GetName() and GetCount() and lookup the cost for each item in the external table (map or hash table).

Answer (score -1):

```
class Purchase  
{  
    private:  
        items *arr;  
        int max_items,current_items;  
        **int sum;**  
    public:  
        Purchase(int New_max_items){  
            max_items=New_max_items;  
            current_items=0;  
            arr= new items("",0,0)[max_items];  
            **sum = 0;**  
        }  
.  
.  
.
```

In `AddItems()` increment the price and in `RemoveItems()` decrement it ;)

Comment: `AddItems` gets a `items` parameter, how do you want to "increment" you sum attribute with that?

Comment: You said you cant change Items class ,so change purchase class ...instead of parameter as 'Item' take 3 parameters and then increment the sum accordingly ..   Possible??